# .h file exists, But no .cpp file

Tags: rsync, checksum

I'm analyzing a source code to understand algorithm to calculate week and strong checksum. Source code is here (rSync source code) http://sourceforge.net/projects/librsync/. In header file librsync.h, there is a method called rs_mdfour() is defined. but I couldn't find the implementation of that method. because there is no file named librsync.c. Is the method  implemented somewhere else?
method definition:

```
void rs_mdfour(unsigned char *out, void const *in, size_t);
```

please somebody help me. 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined in `mdfour.c`, line 384.

Just download the source code, unpacked it, opened a terminal, changed directory to the root of directory of the project and ran:

```
grep -r rs_mdfour *
```

Note: There is no rule that says an implementation must be in a file that equals the name of the header where it is defined. An implementation can be in any file, just like the definition, as long as the compiler sees the definition every time before the function is used and as long as the liker can find the implementation when it links everything together.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, You can right click -> go to definition.

Comment: Thanks. I use QT creator. But now I'm going through source code in normal editor.

Comment: You could search for this method signature in every file that's included in the package. If you don't find anything, it probably doesn't exist?\